# Lookig to integrate push notifications among users inside HTML5/jquerymobile/PHP/MySQL application

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-mobile, push-notification

I have an existing PHP/MySQL application, which is coded in jquery mobile framework, so ti looks like an app, although it runs like a normal web page.

I would like to add the functionality, which would allow users to invite (send push notification) other users to join them in the tennis match. When the user would receive such invitation, he would respond with YES/NO and the response should be inserted in MySQL.

My question is, which solution should I be looking for? Our users use IOS, Android, Windows and all other possible systems, that is why we have build an independent jquery mobile app.

I would prefer a free library or solution if possible. I expect around 200 msgs to be sent out daily.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at Websockets: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

All the platforms you mentioned support it.

Here is a PHP library http://socketo.me/

Comment: So do I need the one on the first link or the second link you have provided?

Comment: All of them. You need a server to handle the websocket traffic (using PHP or some other language, I prefer NodeJS).  Then the clients send and receive data from the server over websockets.